# Bug ? Seq.take 10 works well , Seq.take 100 doesn't work

Tags: f#, sequence, take

```
let a = [1;2;3;]

for i in (a |> Seq.take 10) do Console.WriteLine(i)
for i in (a |> Seq.take 100) do Console.WriteLine(i)
```

first line works well but second line gives error : **The input sequence has an insufficient number of elements.**

Yes , there is no 100 elements , they are just 3 but why 10 works then ?

[Online test](http://ideone.com/GlEAv)

after all it works on C#

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{ static void Main() {

 var p = new[] {1,2,3,4};

 foreach(var i in p.Take(10).ToArray()) Console.WriteLine(i);
 foreach(var i in p.Take(2).ToArray()) Console.WriteLine(i);
 foreach(var i in p.Take(100).ToArray()) Console.WriteLine(i);
}}
```

[Online test](http://ideone.com/HOviz)

Comment: Seq.take 10 doesn't work for me either. you'd better double check it.

Comment: Compare your online-test with this: http://ideone.com/WAyj0 It fails during the first loop already. It just prints the first 3 elements, before failing.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer ... yes I already understood.

Comment: Downvotes a little unfriendly here I think, OP made a simple mistake, but took time to document the question well and is clearly trying out F# and has pointed out a difference between take in F# vs C#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's printing out 3 elements and then printing out the error message.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers have explained your mistake (and I recommend [trying not to jump to conclusions about compiler bugs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html), you'll probably be downvoted). Also, you're comparing Seq.take with Enumerable.Take, but [they don't have the same behavior](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/08/enumerableskip-vs-seqskip.html). However, Seq.truncate *does* have the same behavior as Enumerable.Take

Comment: I see . Output confused me, I think let x = Enumerable.Take myList 5 must works then.

Comment: +1 for linking to a blog post that mentions that `Seq.truncate` does what the OP is expecting `Seq.take` to do, but it wouldn't hurt to say so explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

in your sample second for loop is not executed at all. first one outputs 1 2 3 and then throws exception